Why does the three.js stl loader not show anything?
I'm trying to render an STL in my react app by using the STL Loader from Three.js. It does not show anything on the canvas but also doesn't throw any error. What could be the reason?


import "./App.css";
import { STLLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader";
import { Canvas, useLoader  } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {  ArcballControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Suspense } from "react";
 
const Scene = ({ url }) => {
  const obj = useLoader(STLLoader, url);
  return <primitive object={obj}  scale={1} />;
};
 
 
export default function RenderedModelSTL ({ url }) {    
  return (
    <div className="model-wrapper">
      <Canvas camera={{fov: 18}} color="third">
        <Suspense fallback={"loading..."}>
          <ambientLight intensity={1} />
          <Scene url={url} />
          <ArcballControls />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}



